# Best practice for improving type-stability of `hvcat`?

Tags: julia

Please take a look at the following MWE:

```
julia> function foo()
        # do something
        R = rand(3,3)
        t = rand(3)
        y = [  R   t;
             0 0 0 1]
        # do something
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  #self#::#foo
  R::Array{Float64,2}
  t::Array{Float64,1}

Body:
  begin
      # ..........................
      R::Array{Float64,2} = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand!(::MersenneT
wister, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int64, ::Type{Base.Random.CloseOpen}), :(Base.Rand
om.rand!), :(Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG), SSAValue(4), :((Base.arraylen)(SSAValue(4)
)::Int64), :(Base.Random.CloseOpen))) # line 3:
      # .............................
      t::Array{Float64,1} = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand!(::MersenneT
wister, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64, ::Type{Base.Random.CloseOpen}), :(Base.Rand
om.rand!), :(Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG), SSAValue(8), :((Base.arraylen)(SSAValue(8)
)::Int64), :(Base.Random.CloseOpen))) # line 4:
      return $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for hvcat(::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Ar
ray{Float64,2}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N), :(Main.hvcat), (2, 4), :(R), :(t), 0,
0, 0, 1))
  end::Any
```

It shows that `hvcat` can't infer the type because it needs to know the size of `R` and `t` which is not compile time info. My current workaround is to write something like this:

```
y = zeros(4,4)
y[1:3,1:3] = R
y[:,4] = [t; 1]
```

But it looks a little bit cumbersome, is there any concise way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the scalar parameters with Array typed ones seems to do the trick:

```
function foo()
    # do something
    R = rand(3,3)
    t = rand(3)
    y = [  R   t;
      [0 0 0 1]]        # <-- the change is here
    # do something
end
```

The `@code_warntype` is:

```
julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  R::Array{Float64,2}
  t::Array{Float64,1}
  y <optimized out>

Body:
  begin 
⋮
⋮
  return SSAValue(0)
end::Array{Float64,2}
```

Comment: Thx @Dan, you just saved my afternoon! I find your "array typed method" triggered an undocumented function `Base.typed_hvcat` which seems what I was looking for.

Comment: `vcat([R t], [0 0 0 1])` is also type-stable, interestingly, both methods are implemented in [sparse\sparsevector.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/903644385b91ed8d95e5e3a5716c089dd1f1b08a/base/sparse/sparsevector.jl#L982-L991)